# Magento - Passing a session variable to a page called via _redirect()

Tags: magento, redirect, session-variables, logout

I have the need to pass a URL to Magento, where it should redirect the User after completing the logout. To store it, I do the following:

```
$BackTo = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('backto');

if(!empty($BackTo)) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBackTo($BackTo);
}
```

When needed, I retrieve the URL using `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getBackTo()`. The issue is that, while this works well on login, it doesn't work on logout (where it's most needed). I can store the session variable, I can also immediately retrieve it, but, when I am in `logout.phtml`, where the redirect JavaScript is located, such variable is set to `null`.

I suspect that the redirect performed by Magento upon logout has something to do with this "disappearing" session variable, but I can't say for sure.

For completeness, here is the relevant code (there's more code than this, but they are mainly auxiliary functions, which don't get called on logout).

**Account Controller**

```
class MyPackage_Redirectplugin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
    /**
     * @see AccountController:logoutAction()
     */
    public function logoutAction() {
        $this->_getSession()
            ->logout()
            ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());

        // Store the "back to" URL in a session variable
        $this->StoreBackToURL();

        $this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess');
    }

protected function StoreBackToURL() {
    // Store the value of the "backto" argument, if it was passed
    $BackTo = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('backto');

    if(!empty($BackTo)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBackTo($BackTo);
        // At this point I can see the correct value stored in the session variable
    }
}

}
```

**Logout.phtml**

```
// The following command returns null
$redirectURL = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getBackTo();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update 12/09/25 - Found a workaround**

Since I couldn't find a way to pass a session variable to the logout page opened by redirect, I chose an alternative way: I'm passing it via the URL. Specifically, I implemented a `logoutAction()` which calls `$this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess', array('myvar' => $MyValue));`.

In the template, where I have to do the redirect, I simply read such parameter using `Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('myvar'));`.

I'm aware that there might have been better ways to implement the whole thing, but I needed a bug fix solution and this does the job. Thanks to all people who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 12/09/25 - Found a workaround**
*This workaround has also been posted in the question itself.*

Since I couldn't find a way to pass a session variable to the logout page opened by redirect, I chose an alternative way: I'm passing it via the URL. Specifically, I implemented a `logoutAction()` which calls `$this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess', array('myvar' => $MyValue));.`

In the template, where I have to do the redirect, I simply read such parameter using `Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('myvar'));`.

I'm aware that there might have been better ways to implement the whole thing, but I needed a bug fix solution and this does the job. Thanks to all people who answered.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest option which I see (no controller rewrite necessary!) is to observe the dynamically-dispatched `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout` event - see the [relevant line from`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::postDispatch()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L545). The `postDispatch()` method is called after the controller action completes.

Example observer method:

```
public function logoutRedirect($obs)
{
    $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl(/* url args */);
    $obs->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
}
```

Doing this will redirect the user to the desired URL directly upon logout meaning that the logoutSuccess page with the JS redirect will *not* be accessed.

If the desire is to have the logoutSuccess page render as normal, but redirect to a different URL, this can be achieved a couple of ways:
1. By creating a custom template
2. By creating a custom template block class, overriding the `getUrl()` method to retrieve the URL of your choice, and assigning that as block to render in the content area (by removing or displacing the [`customer_logout`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml#L112) block) in a custom layout XML update file.

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is that 100% of the module has been already implemented overriding the Controller and, in theory, it should work. It implements a new logout page template, which tries to retrieve the "where should I redirect you" value and do the redirect. The whole logic is clear and simple: receive the destination URL, save it somewhere, when it's time to redirect retrieve it and send the user there. Thing is, the session variable "disappears" when the new layout is rendered, and I can't understand why.

Comment: I still appreciate your suggestion, though, it simply not feasible for me to rewrite the whole plugin (I didn't write it in first place, I barely understand the basics of Magento).

Answer (score 1):

just observe this event customer_logout, and when event call method you save the session key on database.
Learn more: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

GL.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I replied to benmarks, intercepting the logout and redirecting somewhere else is not the issue here. The whole plugin already does the job, it just fails when it's time to store the destination URL in the session variables and pass it to the new logout.phtml, which will do the redirect. I thought of the database, but it's an overkill to create a table, a model and the whole (slow) ORM stuff just to pass a string from a page to another, therefore that route is not viable. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.